# como obtener datos en un slider de valores en angular 4

Tags: bootstrap, angular

Estoy usando Angular 4, no puedo extraer el valor maximo y minimo desde un slider de datos (valores), la cosa es que cuando lo obtengo en un input me aparece pero junto como esta especificado en el input del slider data-slider-value. Por favor alguna sugerencia para poder obtener los valores juntos o separados, ojala separados.

Este es el hatml, en donde tengo mi form y el slider que quiero obtener el valor mayor y menor. Ademas abajo tengo un input en donde le paso el valor, funciona pero pasa ambos valores, mayor y menor y no cambia al deslizar el slide (es estatico).

```html
<!-- Filter-Form -->
<section id="filter_form2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main_bg white-text">
      <h3>Busca Tu Auto Nuevo!</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <form (ngSubmit)="buscar($event)">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group select">
              <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tipoAuto" name="tipoAuto">
                <option value="0">Seleccione Tipo de Auto</option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of categorias" id="{{c.id}}">{{c.nombre}}</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <label class="form-label">Rango de Precios ($) </label>
            <input [(ngModel)]="precioTipoAuto" #slider name="precioTipoAuto" id="price_range" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="1000000" data-slider-max="300000000" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="[50000000,200000000]"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> Buscar Auto</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 black-text">
            <input type="text" id="precioMayor" value="{{precioTipoAuto.value}}">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /Filter-Form -->
```

aca esta el .ts, en donde intento obtener los datos del formulario, el buscar() es en donde se ejecuta cuando le preciono buscar auto, lo imprimo en console.log y este solo me trae el valor del select (extrae el dato correctamente), en cambio el precioTipoAuto me sale como valor indefinido (ya lo intente cambiar a string y array, los 2 tipos me dieron un undefined en console).

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AutoService } from '../../auto/auto.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-form-busqueda',
  templateUrl: './home-form-busqueda.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-form-busqueda.component.css'],
})
export class HomeFormBusquedaComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() emitEvent:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  buscarForm: FormGroup;

  public categorias: any = [];
  public errorMesage: string;
  public tipoAuto: any = '';
  public varTipoAuto: any = '';
  public precioTipoAuto: any = [];
  public varPrecioTipoAuto: any = [];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private _autoService: AutoService
  ) { }

  getCategorias() {
    return this._autoService.getCategorias().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.categorias = data;
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMesage = error;
      }
    );
  }

  buscar() {
    this.varTipoAuto = this.tipoAuto;
    this.varPrecioTipoAuto = this.precioTipoAuto.value;
    console.log('Categoría: ' + this.varTipoAuto);
    console.log(this.varPrecioTipoAuto);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategorias();
  }

}
```

Comment: ¿Un slider es un `<select>' ?

Comment: es el input, esta con bootstrap y en el label dice rango de precios, ese es el slider.

Comment: Tienes `this.varPrecioTipoAuto = this.precioTipoAuto.value`, pero ¿no sería simplemente `this.varPrecioTipoAuto = this.precioTipoAuto`?

Comment: lo intente, no me imprime nada en console y no da error tampoco que muestre en console